# SQL LIKE expression gives empty result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-like

It seems that using Like requires some exact formatting, which I am not aware of.
This is the code:

```
private void DoFilter()
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName = @filter + '%'", connection))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", txtFilter.Text.Trim());

        DataTable TCustomers = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(TCustomers);

        lstCustomers.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        lstCustomers.ValueMember = "Id";
        lstCustomers.DataSource = TCustomers;

    }
}
```

The code does not raise any error. It just leaves the ListBox (lstCustomers) empty. (txtFilter is a TextBox, in which the filter string is).

Comment: You need the [like operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) for the like to actually work.

Comment: In addition to `LIKE`, [avoid using `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Use strongly-type parameter types with maximum string length to improve performance and promote cache reuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `like operator` instead of `=`

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName like @filter + '%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a `LIKE` operator, you are using the `=` operator.

It should be:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName LIKE @filter + '%'", connection))
```

The way you have written it, SQL will match an exact string with a `%` at the end, and hence you don't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

'Like' should be used as (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName LIKE @filter + '%'):

```
private void DoFilter()
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName LIKE @filter + '%'", connection))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", txtFilter.Text.Trim());

        DataTable TCustomers = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(TCustomers);

        lstCustomers.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        lstCustomers.ValueMember = "Id";
        lstCustomers.DataSource = TCustomers;

    }
}
```